# How to get <option> selected dynamically in php?

Tags: php, html

I have one code like-

```
$row['slots']=8;
                <select name="branch_slot"  class="input" required="required">
                    <option>--------SELECT SLOT-------</option>
                    <?php
                    for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)                   
                    {
                        if($i % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<option"; 
                                if($i==$row['slots'])
                                { 
                                    echo "selected";
                                } 
                            echo ">".$i."</option>";
                       }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

I want that the option where $i gets equal to $row['slots'] which is 8, is to be selected. but by above code the option where it occurs the option is not displayed.
How to solve this? I want that this particular value should be default selected.

Comment: What is this line ==>`if($i % 2 == 0)` use for?? because if your condisiton just if $i equal to $row['slot'] i think this line is unneccesary

Comment: You should really consider using a templating engine such as Twig...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
              for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)                   
                {
                    if($i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                            if($i==$row['slots'])
                            { 
                                echo "<option selected>" . $i . "</option>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";
                            }
                   }
                }
```

hope this code can help you

Answer (score 0):

Give a space before "selected"

```
$row['slots']=8;
                <select name="branch_slot"  class="input" required="required">
                    <option>--------SELECT SLOT-------</option>
                    <?php
                    for($i=0;$i<=14;$i++)                   
                    {
                        if($i % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<option"; 
                                if($i==$row['slots'])
                                { 
                                    echo " selected";
                                } 
                            echo ">".$i."</option>";
                       }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you should always check the rendered HTML in the browser itself - there you would see some "strange" `<optionselected>` tag.